# Elongation of rod

Tags: elasticity

If a force is applied on a unconstrained body lying on a smooth floor ,will it elongate?

My thoughts-as force is applied on body ,it moves with some acceleration,but as it is not constrained it will not expand

Comment: Think about pulling a slinky across the floor for an exaggerated example.

Answer (score 2):

If the rod is accelerating to the right, and we arbitrarily divide the rod in half, the net force exerted on the right half is equal to the applied force F to the right minus the tension that the left half applies on the right half $T_{1/2}$:
$$F-T_{1/2}=\frac{m}{2}a$$So $$T_{1/2}=F-\frac{m}{2}a$$So the rod is under tension (at least at the middle), and it must be stretching.  More generally, the tension on rod at an arbitrary location x measured from the left end is:$$T(x)=F-m\left(1-\frac{x}{L}\right)a=F-F\left(1-\frac{x}{L}\right)=F\frac{x}{L}$$So the tension in the rod increases linearly from 0 at the left end to F at the right end.  The tension in the rod causes it to expand (although not uniformly).

Comment: Apparently nobody remarked that answer depends on how force is
applied. It is very different if you apply force very gently or
abruptly. In first case you will cause a gradual elongation, as
already described. But if applied force jumps in a short time from
zero to a finite constant value, rod will begin to oscillate
longitudinally, while its c.o.m. is accelerating. In other words, a
longitudinal wave is excited along the rod. As time goes on, if force
stays constantly applied the wave will fade away and rod will remain
steadily elongated (but not in a uniform fashion).

Comment: @Elio Fabri Good point.  I tried to stay away from mentioning that because I wanted to try to keep the answer at the level of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the rod will definitely elongate. Think about about a crossection of width dx and at an distance x from the end then as tis particle is not in equilibrium it will have a net force of tension  that tries to stretch it and increase it's length

Answer (score -1):

The rod's length will increase if the force pulls it, but the length will decrease if the force pushes it.